AWS SAMのテンプレート(Typescript)からpackage.jsonの一元化について
添付画像のようにpackage.jsonをが各Handler毎に作成されることはベストプラクティスなのでしょうか
srcのような上位フォルダを作成してpackage.jsonを一元化した方が良いと考えています
その場合template.yamlのどの部分を修正すればよいのでしょうか
既存では各Handlerのpackage.jsonを見ているようで削除するとビルドに失敗します
ビルドエラー
Starting Build use cache
Building codeuri: C:\sample\samLambda\src\hello-world runtime: nodejs18.x architecture: x86_64 functions: HelloWorldFunction
Building codeuri: C:\sample\samLambda\src\second-word runtime: nodejs18.x architecture: x86_64 functions: AAAHelloWorldFunction
package.json file not found. Bundling source without installing dependencies.
package.json file not found. Bundling source without installing dependencies.
 Running NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:EsbuildBundle
 Running NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:EsbuildBundle

Build Failed
Error: NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:EsbuildBundle - Esbuild Failed: Cannot find esbuild. esbuild must be installed on the host machine to use this feature. It is recommended to be installed on the PATH, but can also be included as a project dependency.

template.yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  samLambda

  Sample SAM Template for samLambda

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

    Tracing: Active
    # You can add LoggingConfig parameters such as the Logformat, Log Group, and SystemLogLevel or ApplicationLogLevel. Learn more here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-function-loggingconfig.
    LoggingConfig:
      LogFormat: JSON
  Api:
    TracingEnabled: true
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src/hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Architectures:
      - x86_64
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
    Metadata: # Manage esbuild properties
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Minify: true
        Target: es2020
        Sourcemap: true
        EntryPoints:
        - app.ts
  AAAHelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src/second-word/
      Handler: app.aaalambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Architectures:
      - x86_64
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /aaaa
            Method: get
    Metadata: # Manage esbuild properties
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Minify: true
        Target: es2020
        Sourcemap: true
        EntryPoints:
        - app.ts
        

  ApplicationResourceGroup:
    Type: AWS::ResourceGroups::Group
    Properties:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: ApplicationInsights-SAM-${AWS::StackName}
      ResourceQuery:
        Type: CLOUDFORMATION_STACK_1_0
  ApplicationInsightsMonitoring:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationInsights::Application
    Properties:
      ResourceGroupName:
        Ref: ApplicationResourceGroup
      AutoConfigurationEnabled: 'true'
Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: Hello World Lambda Function ARN
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn



